# Prove or disprove: There exists a prime p > 3 such that p + 2 and p + 4 are also prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I'm having a lot of difficulties with this proof. Can someone please solve it and explain to me what's going on at each step? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $n, n+2, n+4$ all  have different remainders when you divide by $3$.

Comment: I proved the theorem for n = 2. Is that not enough?

Comment: @Adam - no... for example, why doesn't 37 work? or 59? or 107?

Answer (score 4):

Following my hint in the comments, one of the numbers $\{n,n+2, n+4\}$ must always be a multiple of $3$.  However the hypotheses of the problem are that all three are prime.  Hence one of them must be the specific prime $3$, as that is the only prime number that is also a multiple of $3$.  So there are three cases:

1. $n=3$.  Excluded, since $p>3$ forbids $p=3$.
2. $n+2=3$.  Then $n=1$, which is not prime.
3. $n+4=3$.  Then $n=-1$, which is also not prime.

Comment: +1 but why did you use "n" at all?

Comment: Because $p$ is always prime, while $n$ may or may not be.

Comment: @vadim123 why must one of the numbers be a multiple of 3?

Comment: @shoestringfries, because $n, n+2, n+4$ all give different remainders when you divide by $3$, and there are only three possible remainders.

Answer (score 1):

$p$ must be odd and greater than $3$. Thus

$$~~~~~p + 2 \equiv 2 \pm 1 \pmod 3$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  p + 4 \equiv 1 \pm 1 \pmod 3$$

If the sign is plus, $p+2 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. If the sign is minus, $p+4 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. In either case, one of these numbers is divisible by $3$, and since they can't be $3$ themselves by assumption, they cannot be prime.

Comment: So the theorem is disproven?

Comment: @Adam Yes, through reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: Got it. Thanks mate!